# Why is iPhone not allowing access to microphone, camera for all the apps that I use?

Tags: ios, settings, camera, microphone, versions

My apps do not have camera access or microphone access.
I tried to delete and re-install Instagram, WhatsApp, and phone pe apps but it did not resolve the issue.
I even tried to reset the location still the issue persists.

Comment: Have you looked inside the settings for each app?

Comment: @agarza yes I did